# Laravel MySQL: Designing multi(three) level category structure for ecommerce

Tags: mysql, laravel

In my project the categories are in three levelst

> Main-Category || Category || Subcategory

example

> Bags || backpacks || small-backpacks

Children can belong to multiple parents.

And product has to belong to all three levels of the categories

What kind of relation should I use?

Comment: belongsToMany. You pretty much answered your own question by writing it out.

Comment: Thank you. Would that be use pivot table?